# Continuity of the function defined by it's measure

Tags: measure-theory

The question is as follows:

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set with $0<m(A)<\infty$. Define $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=m(A\cap(-\infty,x])$. Show that this is continuous.

My attempt is as follows: For a given $\epsilon>0$, let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$. Then:

$$ |f(x)-f(y)|=|m(A\cap(-\infty,x])-m(A\cap(-\infty,y])|$$

$$=|m(A\cap(-\infty,x])-m\big((A\cap(-\infty,x])\cup(A\cap(x,y])\big)|=|m(A\cap (x,y])|\leq m(x,y)=y-x<\delta$$

Letting $\delta=\epsilon$ gives our desired result

Is there anything wrong in my logic? I feel that it's reasonable, but I'm not entirely certain

Comment: I think you technically need to use the fact that $A$ has finite measure explicitly.

Comment: @Ian Where do you think it is applicable? At the part where $m(A \cap (-\infty, x])$ cancels with itself?  Is it because otherwise we could have $\infty - \infty$?

Comment: @user46944 Right. You can only be sure that you have the excision property with finite measure sets.

Comment: @Ian That makes me wonder something.  We know $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} (x - x) = 0$.  But is $(\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} x) - (\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} x )$ undefined?  Even though we are subtracting the same quantity from itself?

Comment: @user46944 That's right.

Comment: Ah, of course! I completely forgot to use that fact.... hahaha. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: suppose $x_n$ increases to $x$. Then $A \cap (-\infty,x_n]$ is an increasing sequence of sets, whose measure converges to $m(A \cap (-\infty,x))=m(A \cap (-\infty,x])$ by continuity of measure from below, along with the fact that the measure of a singleton is zero. Here we do not need that $A$ has finite measure.

If you suppose $x_n$ decreases to $x$, then because $A$ has finite measure you can use continuity of measure from above to get the convergence you want.

To finish, note that if $x_n$ converges to $x$, then any subsequence $x_{n_k}$ contains a monotone subsequence $x_{n_{k_\ell}}$; now use one of the standard lemmas from real analysis about convergence of subsequences.